# Should I delete this question and re-ask?

Tags: discussion, designer-reasons

I recently asked a question about [undead having darkvision](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63260/12011).

I felt that the original question was pretty unambiguously worded, but apparently I was wrong as the answers don't really match what I was looking for at all. I've asked a [related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92064/are-zombies-traditionally-portrayed-as-being-able-to-see-in-the-dark) on Sci-Fi and Fantasy SE, which was almost closed. This question is focusing on my curiosity regarding other media.

I think I should delete the original question here, and write a new one that is more clearly worded, making it clear that I'm interested in the reason behind the game designers decision. If this happens to be other media, great, if it happens to be an in-universe justification, great, if somebody did it for kicks, great. I'm just curious why, as it seems like an extremely odd decision to me.

Does that sound like a reasonable course of action?

Comment: There is also the option of just leaving it there and getting it closed, then re-asking it. No need for deletion.

Comment: If you really intend for a tightly scoped "why did the game designers decide this, originally" you can ask it but are not going to get any answer that shouldn't be deleted... Unless someone digs out some old Gygax quote, and that's unlikely.  It's pretty obvious that most undead in lore are fine in the dark and it's pretty obvious that's why, and later versions just inherit that design decision from earlier ones.

Comment: @mxyzplk I don't think that it's obvious at all. If I did, I wouldn't ask about it. Piecing together information, it sounds like maybe the designers gave them infra-vision to match a particular movie, and then that changed to darkvision for convenience.

Comment: @DCShannon the issue we have is proving that. 'Its pretty obvious' is basically personal opinion, and would not count as an answer if you are looking for designer intent

Answer (score 3):

### Do not delete it

I would actually expect the moderators to un-delete it if you did. There is useful and interesting information that users put time and effort into; the question, and its accompanying answers, are no longer yours to delete. That you asked your question poorly and it was misunderstood by *everyone who read it* is an issue that lies squarely on your shoulders; it is not a cause to delete.

It’s also not, in itself, a problem for the site. OK, not exactly what you meant to ask, got answers that don’t really help you: oops. It’s still a useful question that got useful answers, even if they aren’t useful answers *to you*. Probably shouldn’t accept any of the answers, since the definition of acceptance is helping you, but that’s fine too. Let it lie, let the answerers enjoy the fruits of their labors and let the rest of the community enjoy the useful and interesting information that they are offering.

### Do consider asking a new question

You are not limited in how many questions you can ask. Made mistakes asking this one, it got answers that don’t help you: no problem, try again. No need to delete it; you can just have both.

### You have the option to dissociate with the question, if you are *really* annoyed by it

You can remove it from your profile, and your name from the question. This is your only option, since as mentioned it is no longer yours to delete. I don’t see why you would want to, but you can. See the FAQ: [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC:WIKI?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/190917)

Comment: mxyzplk edited his comment into an actual answer, so it's probably fine now. I mostly wanted to delete it because asking another version of the same question would make a duplicate (in my mind, but maybe not in others?), but just editing my question would invalidate the answers (which I already thought were invalid, but apparently others disagree).